# After solving cors problems a post on ajax from a virtual machine return error 500, request failed

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, post

I am trying to do a POST on a server from a virtual machine running virtualbox windows 7. And the server is running local on the same machine, but on a linux.
Initially it had CORS problems, then I downloaded the CORS chrome extension 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:', '*' from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=pt-BR.

After I downloaded the chrome extension, the cors problem stopped. But now what cames to me is the message: 
POST http://servidor.hanbai:8081/api/aa/v1/pedidos 500 (Request failed.)

The only message besides this, is a warning saying:
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://servidor.hanbai:8081/api/aa/v1/pedidos with MIME type application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

But when I try on POSTMAN, no problem occur. What might be?

```
function enviaParaHanbai(pedido) {
console.log(pedido);
let urlPedidoCriado;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://servidor.hanbai:8081/api/aa/v1/pedidos",
        data: JSON.stringify(pedido),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        },
        success: function(data, status, request) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(request);
            urlPedidoCriado = request.getResponseHeader('location');
            console.log(urlPedidoCriado);
            const regex = /(?<=pedidos\/).*$/gi;
            let match = regex.exec(urlPedidoCriado);
            let idPedidoCriado = match[0];
            console.log(idPedidoCriado);
            renderizaDivPedidoRealizadoComSucesso(idPedidoCriado);
        },
        error: function (data, status, request) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(request);
            console.log(status);
            console.log("erro no envio do pedido para o hanbai");
        }
});
}
```

Comment: Check the server logs on the server side of the `http://servidor.hanbai:8081/api/aa/v1/pedidos` server. Look for any messages the server is logging there about the internal server failure which leads to the server ending up sending that 500 response. (A 500 error indicates an internal server failure. It’s caused by broken code on the server side. So the only way to fix it is by changing code on the server side. There are no changes you can make to your frontend JavaScript code that will fix it.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Chrome extension to enable CORS, use this guide to help you add the headers to your server (https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled). As for the error, try adding a `dataType` parameter to your ajax call and specify the data. Other than that, install Fiddler and debug it. Hope that helps